# Move policy tag to another tier without losing policy tag being removed from columns

Tags: google-bigquery

We have a defined a taxonomy with every policy tag at the same tier level, like this:

- Policy_tag 1
- Policy_tag 2
- Policy_tag 3

Now, we want to have those policy tags one nested into the other, like this:

- Policy_tag 1

  - Policy_tag 2

    - Policy_tag 3

However, we've already assigned those tags to multiple table columns, and we couldn't find any way to move the tags besides deleting and recreating them (which would also lose the columns current tags).

Is there a way, from the GUI, CLI or API, to nest the tags while keeping them assigned to the columns?

Answer (score 0):

Seems easiest to treat this as a migration problem.  Create the new nested versions of the policy tags, migrate references, then delete the old flat tags that are no longer used.

You should be able to issue table update calls where policytags are used to update the policy tag references in the schema.